# Redirect from xxx.com to full FQDN URL

Tags: 2013, iis, alternate-access-mapping

In SharePoint 2013 I have created a web application and published it to Internet with avalid https certificate

AAM:

```
Default: https://www.xxxx.com
```

IIS bindings:

```
Hostname: www.xxxxx.com
```

My requirement is when user browse only `xxx.com` (only domain name) in browser it should be redirect to Full FQDN url (`https://xxxx.com`)

Comment: AAM is not about redirection... Also, in your question, relations you want between www.xxxx.com, xxxx.com and xyz.com is not clear. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make sure that a server (doesn't have to be the SharePoint server) responds to `example.com`.

On that server, you could use a redirection technique. If using IIS, you can configure a 301 (permanent) redirect, from `http://example.com` -> `https://www.xxxx.com`.

Using IIS Manager, go to Sites -> the site responding to `http://example.com`, then go into HTTP Redirect. Enter an address to redirect to (`https://www.xxxx.com`) and select a status code of "Permanent (301)".

This is the easiest way to do this. Another option would be using IIS Redirect. An example can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx.